# Raw JS AJAX method

Tags: javascript, ajax, reinventing-the-wheel

I built this as a simple example of using raw JS to perform a simple GET request with a data callback.

Suggestions on how this could be improved in any way, while keeping it simple, would be much appreciated.

JS:

```
/*jslint unparam: true, white: true */

var app = (function() {
    "use strict";

    return {
        ajax: function(url, callback) {

            var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                var data;

                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    data = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    };

}());
```

Example usage:

```
app.ajax('file.json', function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.name);
});
```

Comment: you are aware this is not cross-browser compatible? [here's something I used when I did something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15640875/1803692)

Comment: @Vogel612 Do you mean with regards to IE6/7?

Comment: yea. Don't expect ppl. on public websites to have current browsers. no offense if you don't implement it though ;) It's just a hassle for that minimal helpfulnes.

Comment: I don't really care that much about IE6/7 support. Thanks for pointing this out anyway.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, it is considered bad form to update this question because it puts answer <> question out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over:

- There should be a way to handle errors, this is only good for sunny day scenarios
- It would be more useful if you also passed the `xmlhttp` object to the callback : `callback(data, xmlhttp);`
- As stated by Vogel612, it wont work for some versions of IE, it's not hard to add support for those
- There is no need at all to declare `data`, you can pass `xmlhttp.responseText;` straight to `callback`, it would make the code tighter
- A comment as to what `4` and `200` stand for could be useful for the unaware reader

Other than that, looks good.

Comment: Here at Code Review we don't like magic numbers +1 !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the solution in the original question.